# How can I get better at math?

Tags: soft-question

I am a high school junior taking calculus AB. What should I do to become the best I can at math? Can you suggest any books I should read, a list of problems I can do, etc.? Thanks

Comment: While I applaud the sentiment and sympathize with the asker, to my mind this is the archetypical "too localized" question.  The OP wants to know how s/he can get better at math.  This answer depends critically on who s/he is: no one who has taught math (or had substantial human interactions) will think there is an answer about how to learn or improve at something which is the same for everyone (or even for all high school juniors taking AP calculus).  So: to get a meaningful answer, the OP needs to ask someone who actually knows her/him, not post anonymously on an internet forum!

Comment: @Ovi If you want a book that will be helpful to ALL math courses you'll be taking in the future, I recommend [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521446635/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) by [Daniel J.Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: If this was too localized, the post wouldn't get $7$ upvotes versus $1$ down vote. Its appealing towards large audience. Others who possibly cross over this question have something to take from here.

Comment: @Inceptio: Your first assertion does not follow: many questions which are off-topic for the site attract upvotes.  Also, not knowing anything much about the OP, I think many people are reading the question as "What advice can you give *anyone* to get better at math?"  And of course this questions is too broad and subjective for a focused site like this one.  Which is not to say that it's a bad question: it's a great question.  But Math.se is not a site for any good question having something to do with mathematics.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Where does this question belong? Direct him there.:)

Comment: I would say that this question should remain closed as a mixture of not constructive and not a real question. Certainly it is too broad for a good answer, since answers could just as well focus on a choice of courses for the OP to take to obtain a better understanding of maths, recommendations of how to broaden and deeper their current learning experience, advice on $\textit{how}$ to study maths better, resources to better explain the material that they are currently covering, $\dots$. If it were to become much more specific, I would perhaps vote to re-open.

Comment: @Tom: I agree.  It seems paradoxical, but I think the question is both too localized and too broad, and (continuing the paradox) if the OP could enunciate much more specific goals, we could get a question which would be useful for a broader audience and more appropriate for this site.

Comment: OP: sucks that this question had to be closed, but let me second GitGud's recommendation.  How To Prove It will rock your world.

Comment: By the way come by the [chat](chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) sometime and ask about this, we'd be glad to help you there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see if I can get that book and I'll join the chat sometime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just stick to the curriculum.  Read the books published by the Mathematical Association of America for young people who want to find out what mathematics is.  Also, one of my favorites: C. Stanley Ogilvy's *Excursions in Geometry*.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest "[What is Mathematics?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Mathematics?)" book by [Richard Courant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Courant) and [Herbert Robbins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Robbins). A great book. Provides insight about every level of math.